# Pass key values pair as string to JQuery function

Tags: jquery

If I try:

```
$("#test_form").validate({
    rules : {'code':'required'},
```

it works.
If I try:

```
var my_rules="{code : 'required'}";
$("#test_form").validate({
    rules : my_rules,
```

doesn't work.
How I can pass values?
Thanks.

Comment: In the first example you pass an object, in the second a string. If the function does not accept a string then it cannot work. The question is, why do you want to pass a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var my_rules="{"code" : "required"}";provided its an object

```
var obj1 = new object;
obj1.code="required";
```

Comment: I try: var my_rules= new object;
 my_rules.code='required';
   $("#test_form").validate({
    rules : my_rules, dowsn't work

Comment: what are you validating?? why you need for that validation?? you need to destringify before validation.are you doing it ??

Comment: I need to write javascript 1 for many pages. But I have check only inputs that have class "required". So I use jquery selector for class for receive list of elements but now I need construct the rules for validate.

Comment: can u please post your code so that i would be able to answer you more clearly

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotations around `var my_rules="{code : 'required'}";`, like this:

`var my_rules={code : 'required'};`

Because otherwise you are just assigning a `string` to `my_rules` and not an `object`.

Comment: I can remove the quotations mark, but I need construct rules dynamically. For this purpose I use string.

Comment: @Lorenzo: You can add properties dynamically to an object. I suggest to read [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects). I'm pretty sure you don't need a string here.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Works pretty well for me. But you can also google for `mdc working with objects`.